# How to enable Auto-completion of PECL Mongo classes in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, mongodb, pecl

Is there any chance to have/enable auto-completion of Mongo PHP PECL classes in netbeans?

Comment: https://github.com/hollodotme/Helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only found on this is to write PHP class stubs, and put it into netbeans dir

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder which i auto included; external to my project, then from there you can auto-include it and have it referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and I solved it here. Maybe this will help you too.

[How to generate .php files from .dll files for code completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732449/how-to-generate-php-files-from-dll-files-for-code-completion/15737283#15737283)