# How to generate .php files from .dll files for code completion?

Tags: php, mongodb, netbeans, code-completion, pecl

Basically I have just successfully installed MongoDB and it's PHP extension. I want to use code completion in my IDE for the MongoDB php library and closest I have gotten to getting an answer is some stuff about PDT with Eclipse. I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: That's not related to compile .php to .dll at all.

Comment: Need something that does a .dll to .php ... Just the interface of the methods and classes for the sake of code completion in netbeans... it's so hard to work without it. :( every function in the whole API I need to go look up documentation online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after a lot of searching I found some code that helps me do just that! I will include the code here for others to use in case something happens to the git repo. All you have to do is write in the classes and functions you want to stub for code completion into these arrays `$functions = array();`
`$classes = array();` https://gist.github.com/ralphschindler/4757829

```
<?php

define('T', '    ');
define('N', PHP_EOL);

$functions = array();
$classes = array();
$constant_prefix = 'X_';

$php = '<?php' . N;
$php .= '/**' . N . ' * Generated stub file for code completion purposes' . N . ' */';
$php .= N . N;

foreach (get_defined_constants() as $cname => $cvalue) {
    if (strpos($cname, $constant_prefix) === 0) {
        $php .= 'define(\'' . $cname . '\', ' . $cvalue . ');' . N;
    }
}

$php .= N;

foreach ($functions as $function) {
    $refl = new ReflectionFunction($function);
    $php .= 'function ' . $refl->getName() . '(';
    foreach ($refl->getParameters() as $i => $parameter) {
        if ($i >= 1) {
            $php .= ', ';
        }
        if ($typehint = $parameter->getClass()) {
            $php .= $typehint->getName() . ' ';
        }
        $php .= '$' . $parameter->getName();
        if ($parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
            $php .= ' = ' . $parameter->getDefaultValue();
        }
    }
    $php .= ') {}' . N;
}

$php .= N;

foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $refl = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $php .= 'class ' . $refl->getName();
    if ($parent = $refl->getParentClass()) {
        $php .= ' extends ' . $parent->getName();
    }
    $php .= N . '{' . N;
    foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $property) {
        $php .= T . '$' . $property->getName() . ';' . N;
    }
    foreach ($refl->getMethods() as $method) {
        if ($method->isPublic()) {
            if ($method->getDocComment()) {
                $php .= T . $method->getDocComment() . N;                
            }
            $php .= T . 'public function ';
            if ($method->returnsReference()) {
                $php .= '&';
            }
            $php .= $method->getName() . '(';
            foreach ($method->getParameters() as $i => $parameter) {
                if ($i >= 1) {
                    $php .= ', ';
                }
                if ($parameter->isArray()) {
                    $php .= 'array ';
                }
                if ($typehint = $parameter->getClass()) {
                    $php .= $typehint->getName() . ' ';
                }
                $php .= '$' . $parameter->getName();
                if ($parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
                    $php .= ' = ' . $parameter->getDefaultValue();
                }
            }
            $php .= ') {}' . N;
        }
    }
    $php .= '}';
}

echo $php . N;
```